# What type to use for itertools.count in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.8, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to specify the type of an `itertool.count` object in Python, like so:

```py
from itertools import count

c: count = count()
```

However, running `mypy` yields the following error:

```
test.py:3: error: Function "itertools.count" is not valid as a type
test.py:3: note: Perhaps you need "Callable[...]" or a callback protocol?
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

It seems to be caused by the fact that `itertools.count` behaves like a function. However, it returns an `itertools.count` object, as shown by

```py
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: type(itertools.count()) is itertools.count
Out[2]: True
```

Then, how should I specify the type of the result of `count()` ?

Comment: [`typing.Iterator[int]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterator) should work.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks ! Do you know if it is possible to enforce a strict `itertools.count` type ?

Comment: I think itertools types (as well as other types, like `zip` or `map`) are meant to be "opaque", in that the documentation does not specify anything about the type of the returned value them beyond it behaving as an iterator (that is, I think the specific type could change in a different version of Python). That said, I don't know why MyPy does not allow you to use `count` as a type hint, since `type(count)` is `type`, not `function` or `builtin_function_or_method`. Not sure if it's some kind of bug or if there is some documented reason for that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is following annotation in `itertools.pyi`:

```
_N = TypeVar('_N', int, float)

def count(start: _N = ...,
          step: _N = ...) -> Iterator[_N]: ...  # more general types?
```

Thus, in your code, you could do like this:

```py
from typing import Iterator
from itertools import count

c: Iterator[int] = count()
c_i: Iterator[int] = count(start=1, step=1)
c_f: Iterator[float] = count(start=1.0, step=0.1)  # since python 3.1 float is allowed
```